# How do I find more infos about an auto discoverd printer in local network?

Tags: network-printer, ssdp

My printing dialogue shows some printers I don't knwo about. One is called "duerqxesz5090", one "print" and the last one "prt0". prt0 has "Hacked by Swan" as location, so I want to know what device this is. ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6NUg.png))

But I don't know how this printer is discovered and how I find out more about it. Is this done via SSDP?

I am using lubuntu 17.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `avahi-discover` tool gave me the missing information.

Comment: Thank you, good posts! I suggest to extend the answer a little bit (around 2-3 sentences are already okay).